# My Picker shows question marks, but still sends the proper info to my Label

Tags: iphone

I made a simple picker that displays the information chose in a label on the same page.  The picker is just showing ? ? ?, but when i scroll over the ? it shows the correct things chosen in the label.  How do I get it to also show the words in the pickerwheel itself?

Comment: Make sure you have the datasource set. Do not nil the datasource until the view hosting the uipicker is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to track down. How are you setting the information in the Label and the Picker?

If you have an array of strings which are also displayed in the Picker, then this is easy:

In the .h file, use:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>{

  NSArray * arrayOfString;
  UILabel * theLabel;
  UIPicker * thePicker;
}
```

In the .m file, use:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View

- (void)viewDidLoad;{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  arrayOfStrings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"etc", nil];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView; {
  return [arrayOfStrings count];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component; {
  return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component; {
  return [arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component; {
  theLabel.text = [arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

You then hook everything up in the nib, and this should fix your problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, sorry I just noticed it.... here is my code I am using, still having the same problem:

Comment: (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)thePickerView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [list count];
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row ForComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

Comment: NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Selected: %@", [list objectAtIndex:row]];
    pickLabel.text = string;

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [list addObject:@"Small"];
    [list addObject:@"Medium"];
    [list addObject:@"Large"];

Comment: @interface MyPickerViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSArray *arrayOfString;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pickLabel;
}

Comment: list should be an NSMutableArray if you want to do it that way.

It also seems as though you might have a problem with the .h file.

If you look at my above code for the .h file, you'll see that the UIViewController needs to be a UIPickerDelegate AND a UIPickerDataSource.

Then, make sure in the connection tab that pickerView connects the delegate and the dataSource to the File Owner.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?